Woocommerce - Display shipping packages in order emails and on Thank You page
I'm using code posted here by Rodolfo Melogli (WooCommerce: Split Cart Into Packages) to split order shipping into packages based on their shipping class, here's the code:
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'bbloomer_split_shipping_packages_by_class' );
     
    function bbloomer_split_shipping_packages_by_class( $packages ) {
           
       $destination = $packages[0]['destination'];  
       $user = $packages[0]['user']; 
       $applied_coupons = $packages[0]['applied_coupons'];
       $packages = array();
        
       foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {    
          $key = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
          $packages[$key]['contents'][$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
       }
        
       foreach ( $packages as $index => $package ) {
          $total = array_sum( wp_list_pluck( $packages[$index]['contents'], 'line_total' ) );
          $packages[$index]['destination'] = $destination;
          $packages[$index]['user'] = $user;
          $packages[$index]['applied_coupons'] = $applied_coupons;
          $packages[$index]['contents_cost'] = $total;
       }
     
       return $packages;
     
    }

It works perfectly in the cart and checkout, but in the Thank You page and order emails it displays the combined shipping total followed by the names of each shipping class used in a list.
So for example if an order has 3 products each with a different shipping class, they would be listed like so in the cart and checkout:

Shipping: $10.00 via Shipping Class a
Shipping: $10.00 via Shipping Class b
Shipping: $10.00 via Shipping Class c

But in the Thank You page and order emails they are shown as:

Shipping $30.00 via Shipping Class a, Shipping Class b, Shipping Class
c

Is there any way I can echo the shipping packages display from the cart and checkout in the Thank You page and order emails?
